# Traits for both Cloneable types and Copyable types

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I've been writing a fairly simple raster image trait system, but I was also wanting to extend it to work for comma-separated values, and it seems more natural to allow the trait for both pixels (which would have the `Copy` trait), and `String` (which does not).

However, overloading for both causes conflicts. So how would one go about writing a trait which accepts both `Copy`able types and `Clone`able types?

Currently the working definition looks like

```
impl<T:Grid2d,V:Copy> drawable for Line2d{
   fn stroke(&self,out:&mut T);
}
```

This works fine for pixels which are basically integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) is a subtrait of [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) (i.e. all `Copy` types are also `Clone`), so you could have a single `impl` with a bound on `Clone` and it will also accept all `Copy` types.

```
impl<T: Grid2d, V: Clone> Drawable for Line2d {
   fn stroke(&self, out: &mut T);
}
```

You'll have to explicitly call `.clone()` to get a copy of the value, but for `Copy` types, this `.clone()` call should be very cheap (and in release builds, it's likely to be inlined).

Comment: *this `.clone()` call should be very cheap* — more specifically, [it *is* a copy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.3.0/src/libcore/clone.rs#L60-L88). And it is very likely to be inlined.

Comment: You're right. Just changed the copyable requirement to Clone and it works for the types I wanted it to. Thanks